# getting external variables via file - eval/include

Tags: php, variables, external

This should be fairly simple from what I can find online, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've got a widget which I want to enable others to edit (text, images, css, etc). 
so I've provided them the ability to pass an external page in via a url variable.

The problem is that I can't then access the values they provide via the page.

I'm trying to eval via

```
$fileVars=include($getFile);
eval($fileVars);
```

the file I'm being passed contains multiple variables like this

```
$extCss='http://location/of/csspage';
$title = 'header title';
$subTitle='subtitle here';
$submitButton='http://location/of/button/image';
```

I suspected that this should work. 
I'd prefer to not have to put 'echo' on each line because it is just more for other people to muck up later.

Is there something wrong with what I've got here? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `eval` on files uploaded by users is *very* dangerous.  You should never allow anyone else to upload executable files anywhere in your web application.

You would be better off to store these values in a database and let your users alter those.

Edit:  This is much more dangerous because the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables can only hold *values* whereas using `eval` allows someone to inject *executable code*.  This can allow someone to execute malicious code on your server with ease.

```
$files = scandir(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

foreach($files as $file) {
  unlink($file);
}
```

If this was included in a file you parsed with `eval`, it would have just deleted every file in the directory the script was run from.

Comment: why is this any more dangerous than get or post variables. I'm essentially treating them the same way, but getting them via a file rather than get/post.

Comment: ah yes! thank you very much for pointing that out. Is there a way to only receive values from an external page? 
Building a seperate DB to hold this data (there isn't very much, and it won't change often), would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Eval is more dangerous than get/post because the submitted content can run functions like 'include' which can access any file apache has read privileges for, or shell_exec which can do anything in the shell the apache user can do, etc.

get/post variables don't automatically have access to this functionality which is what makes them more secure.